# Getting this error while deploying contract on truffle

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

[image: error message while deploying on truffle]

I am  using command {truffle migrate --network 'Network Name'} to deploy on truffle. I don't know where this error is comming from.
Someone who has worked on truffle, kindly help.